# Find $c$ such that a specific sum converges in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

The problem: We have $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ iid and $\phi(t)= 1-\sqrt{|t|(2-|t|)}$,
$t\in[-1,1]$ and zero elsewhere (characteristic function). Find positive $c$ such that $\frac{S_{n}}{n^{c}}$ converges in some random variable $A$.

My try: The characteristic function of $\frac{S_{n}}{n^{c}}$ for $c=2$  is $z(t)= \Bigl(1-\sqrt{|\frac{t}{n^{2}}|(2-|\frac{t}{n^{2}}|)}\Bigr)^{n}$  , $|\frac{t}{n^{2}}|(2-|\frac{t}{n^{2}}|)$~$|\frac{2t}{n^{2}}|$  .From here i used an argument that i'm not sure if it's ok $\Bigl(1-\sqrt{|\frac{t}{n^{2}}|(2-|\frac{t}{n^{2}}|)}\Bigr)^{n}$~$\Bigl(1-\sqrt{|\frac{2t}{n^{2}}|}\Bigr)^{n}$ and the last part converges in $e^{-(2|t|)^\frac{1}{2}}$,t$\in[-1,1]$ which is continuous at zero.
Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Your text setting like $$\sqrt{(|y|})^n$$ does not make any sense.  Maybe you can fix it to legal notation. Either the exponent is under the root: $$\sqrt{|x|^n}$$ or it is outside: $$\Big(\sqrt{|x|}\Big)^n$$ Ans in some places you have unbalanced `()`.

Answer (score 1):

Update:The argument is fine but it is better to justify the convergence just by the fact that $\sqrt{|t|(2-\frac{|t|}{n^{2}})}$ tends to $(2|t|)^\frac{1}{2}$ as n tends to infinity.I leave the exercise here in case someone would find it helpful.